# Regex pattern to extract substring connected by hyphen-minus

Tags: python, regex

I have the following string variations:

`'001_AML-Micro-CTD_RAM_20220101'`

`'001_RAM_20220101_AML-Micro-CTD'`

`'001_AML-Micro-CTD_RAM_20220101'`

and need to extract the substring `AML-Micro-CTD`.
Basically, any alphanumeric substring connected by `-`.

What is the most robust regex to achieve this?

I tried several regex patterns test on https://pythex.org/ but so far no joy.

[a-zA-Z-] is producing 'AML-Micro-CTD_RAM'

Comment: If you would like to get exact word(s), use it: `AML-Micro-CTD`.

Answer (score 1):

```
words = ['001_AML-Micro-CTD_RAM_20220101', 
    '001_RAM_20220101_AML-Micro-CTD', 
    '001_AML-Micro-CTD_RAM_20220101']
pattern = pattern = r'[a-zA-Z]+-[-a-zA-Z]+'
results = [re.findall(pattern, word) for word in words]
```

yields

```
[['AML-Micro-CTD'], ['AML-Micro-CTD'], ['AML-Micro-CTD']]
```

This assumes the hyphen is never at the start of a substring: every substring starts at least with a letter. I've also assumed numbers can be ignored (but these can be easily added if needs be).

Of course, you don't need a nested list, but this accounts for the possibility of having two such terms in the same string. You can use `re.search` otherwise.

Comment: Thank you. This pattern works for my purpose.

Answer (score 1):

I think a robust pattern would be:

```
(?i)[A-Z\d]+(?:-[A-Z\d]+)+
```

See an online [demo](https://regex101.com/r/X2Lz49/1)

---

- `(?i)` - Case-insensitive modifier;
- `[A-Z\d]+` - 1+ Alphanumeric characters;
- `(?:-[A-Z\d]+)+` - Non-capture group matched 1+ times to assert there is at least 1+ hyphen connected substrings where there is no empty substring allowed, e.g: `test--test`.

---

```
import re
l_in = ['001_AML-Micro-CTD_RAM_20220101', '001_RAM_20220101_AML-Micro-CTD', '001_AML-Micro-CTD_RAM_20220101']
l_out = [re.findall(r'(?i)[A-Z\d]+(?:-[A-Z\d]+)+', x)[0] for x in l_in]
print(l_out)
```

Prints:

```
['AML-Micro-CTD', 'AML-Micro-CTD', 'AML-Micro-CTD']
```